# Extract specific nodes in HTML using Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm want to extract a few values from HTML using Nokogiri in this ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'Nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<-END_OF_HTML)
  <html>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <body style='margin:20px'>
    <p>The following user has registered a device, click on the link below to review the user and make any changes if necessary.</p>
    <ul style='list-style-type:none; margin:25px 15px;'>
      <li><b>User name:</b> Test User</li>
      <li><b>User email:</b> test@abc.com</li>
      <li><b>Identifier:</b> abc123def132afd1213afas</li>
      <li><b>Description:</b> Tom's iPad</li>
      <li><b>Model:</b> iPad 3</li>
      <li><b>Platform:</b> </li>
      <li><b>App:</b> Test app name</li>
      <li><b>UserID:</b> </li>
     </ul>
    <p>Review user: https://cirrus.app47.com/users?search=test@abc.com</p>            <hr style='height=2px; color:#aaa'/>
        <p>We hope you enjoy the app store experience!</p>
        <p style='font-size:18px; color:#999'>Powered by App47</p>
      <img src='https://cirrus.app47.com/notifications/562506219ac25b1033000904/img' alt=''/></body></html>
END_OF_HTML
```

Specifically I want to get the values of the some of the list members like `"Identifier:"` and `"User name:"` and store them in strings.

I'm sure I need to use `xpath` but that's about it. My understanding is that `xpath` does node selection.

What do I need to specify with `xpath` and then how do I get the selection into some variables?

## Full Solution

Ultimately I was really asking two questions.

### Question 1 (implicit): How can I see the results of a search using `xpath`?

```
doc.xpath("SPECIFY_SEARCH_HERE").each do |node|
puts node
end
```

This works because `xpath` returns an array that you can parse and then you can do what you want with the results (in my case, print).

### Question 2: How do I get the value of a particular list item?

```
str = doc.xpath("//ul/li[contains(b, 'Identifier')]/text()").to_s.strip
```

My analysis on this line is limited, but it looks like it does this:

1. Find the location of the li child keys with: `//ul/li`
2. Select the bolded key (`b`) containing 'Identifier'
3. Extract the value of the selection from #2: `/text()`
4. `.to_s.strip` converts the selection to a string and removes leading/trailing whitespace

For anyone better versed in HTML/Ruby/Xpath, feel free to update the explanation for precision.

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty basic. You can use either XPath (with `.xpath`) or CSS-style selectors (with `.css`). Have you read the official [Nokogiri Tutorials](http://www.nokogiri.org/)?

Comment: Specifically `doc.xpath("//Identifier:")` - but I'm getting an error because of the ":". Maybe there is a way to escape it? The tutorials are over my head because I don't really understand HTML structure so it's hard to get a footing on what I can trust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will return both values you asked for

```
//ul/li[contains(b, 'Identifier') or contains(b, 'User name')]/text()
```

Of course you can modify xpath and get only 1 value at one time.

```
//ul/li[contains(b, 'Identifier')]/text()
```

Comment: My main issue with this is the colon (':') character yielding a syntax error. Is there a way to escape it?

Comment: I've updated answer. Just use contains and dont use :